# Dimension of a vector space and span

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If we have a $span${$\left[\begin{matrix}1\\1\\2\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}-2\\0\\1\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}0\\2\\5\end{matrix}\right]$}, how can I compute the dimension of this vector space?

i am a little confused because I think there maybe some mistake.
Thank you a lot because I know this should be an easy question.

Comment: What mistake do you think there is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that: $2(1,1,2)+(-2,0,1)=(0,2,5)$ ; hence : $$\textrm{Span}((1,1,2),(-2,0,1),(0,2,5))=\textrm{Span}((1,1,2),(-2,0,1)).$$
Moreover, $(1,1,2)$ and $(-2,0,1)$ are free. Finally, the subvector space spanned by $(1,1,2),(-2,0,1),(0,2,5)$ is of dimension $2$.

If you want an equation of this subvector space, compute the cross product of $(1,1,2)$ and $(-2,0,1)$ to find an orthogonal vector to the plane they spanned. Finally, one has: $$\textrm{Span}((1,1,2),(-2,0,1),(0,2,5)):x-5y+2z=0.$$

A general way to compute the dimension of the subvector space spanned by a set of vectors is to use [gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination).

Answer (score 0):

I think the dimension of the span of several vectors is actually the number of linear independent vectors in that set.
**Hint: I suggest that here the best way to find the number of linear independent vectors is to do the Gaussian Elimination.**
But I have to create a matrix first.
we know the vectors are $\left[\begin{matrix}1\\1\\2\end{matrix}\right]$ and $\left[\begin{matrix}-2\\0\\1\end{matrix}\right]$ and $\left[\begin{matrix}0\\2\\5\end{matrix}\right]$.
So I choose to make the matrix A=$\left[\begin{matrix}1&-2&0\\1&0&2\\2&1&5\end{matrix}\right]$
After the Gaussian Elimination the result is $\left[\begin{matrix}1&-2&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&0\end{matrix}\right]$ which means that the rank of the matrix A is 2.
In other words it is telling that the demension of the column space of the matrix A is 2, and it is just $span${$\left[\begin{matrix}1\\1\\2\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}-2\\0\\1\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}0\\2\\5\end{matrix}\right]$}.
**Conclusion:**
The dimension of the $span${$\left[\begin{matrix}1\\1\\2\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}-2\\0\\1\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}0\\2\\5\end{matrix}\right]$} is 2.
I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

The dimension of a vector space is the number of vectors in a basis.
And a basis for a vector space is a set of vector that both spans the vector space and is independent.   Here you are given that (1,1,2),(−2,0,1), and (0,2,5)) span the space so we need to determine if this set  is independent or if a  subset is.
If these vectors are independent then the only A,B, C such that A(1,1,2)+ B(-2, 0, 1)+ C(0, 2, 5)= (A- 2B, A+ 2C,2A+ B+ 5C)= (0, 0, 0) are A= B= C= 0. So A- 2B= 0, A+ 2C= 0, 2A+ B+ 5C= 0. A= 2B so 2A+ B+ 5C= 4B+ B+ 5C= 5B+ 5C= 0 and B= -C.
Then A- 2B= 0 and A+ 2C= 0 are the same: B= A/2 and C= -A/2.  So if A= 2, B= 1, and C= -1.  They are NOT all 0 so these vectors are not independent and do not form a basis.  But since they span the vector space, there must be a subspace that still spans the vector space.
Since 2(1,1,2)+ (-2,0,1)-(0,2,5)= (0,0,0) we have
(0,2,5)= 2(1,1,2)+ (-2,0,1). That is we can replace (0,2,5) by 2(1,1,2)+(-2,0,1) and any linear combination of (1,1,2), (-2,0,1), and (0,2,5) can be replaced with just (1,1,2) and (-2,0,1). (1,1,2) and (-2,0,1) also span the space.]
Are they independent? Suppose A(1,1,2)+ B(-2,0,1)= (A-2B,A,2A+B)= (0,0,0).  Then A-2B= 0, A= 0, 2A+B= 0.  Since A= 0, A- 2B= -2B= 0 so B= 0.

So {(1,1,2), (-2, 0, 1)} span the vector space and are independent so form a basis for the vector space.  This vector space has dimension 2.